# How to pass parameter in Gradle build system in Android

Tags: android, gradle, build, configuration

I have a Gradle configuration dependencies sth like this:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
debugCompile project(path: ':app', configuration: 'debug')
releaseCompile project(path: ':app', configuration: 'release')
```

'app' library is mine and I want to pass parameter to this library typing value in thus dependencies. I want to get sth like this:

```
debugCompile project(path: ':app', configuration: 'debug', url: 'test')
releaseCompile project(path: ':app', configuration: 'release', url: 'test')
```

How can achieve this in that way, that I can get it in Gradle configuration file in 'app' library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is why library need it. Why don't you pass those values when you are using the library instead.

Comment: Because I will change this dynamically, when I use different types of Android application.